# Change Hardware Resources During Certain Times Of Day On Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-server-2012, virtual-machines, hardware, cloud, azure

I thought I read you could change the hardware resources during certain times, days, etc for Windows Azure Virtual Machines.  I however don't see this option, am I missing it in the Azure portal or is this not a feature for Virtual Machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Use the Portal's autoscale which allows for timed scaling.  In order for scaling out vm has to be part of an availability set. Instructions on how to add it are on the dashboard for the VM instance. And you must have multiple vm's to scale.

As for scaling up. It does not currently exist from microsoft, there may be a third party tool that allows scaling up.

Both of which are available manually or throught 3rd parties

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect. You can scale out independent of using availability sets; the two concepts are orthogonal. Availability sets allow you to reduce downtime risk by staggering host OS updates, as well as distributing VMs across different fault domains. And... Scale-up is as simple as changing the VM type, either via the portal or via API (which is easily done through PowerShell or cross-platform CLI).

Comment: Why then does the portal say exactly those things?

Comment: Where does the portal say those things? You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: Manage.WindowsAzure.Com -> VM  -> Scale 
"To start using autoscaling, add virtual machines to an availability set"  http://i.imgur.com/jOhDcT0.png

Comment: That's just the built-in autoscale feature, which is scale-out focused and has its limits. That does not equate to Azure not offering scale-up. Many ways to implement scaling. The built-in VM autoscale is just one way, and doesn't cover all scenarios.

Comment: I changed my answer to say auto scale hours ago.  To have it change at times of day 3rd party is the only reasonable option. Powershell is likely not a viable option as it would require a separate sever running at those exact times.